# QTableView: how to set the search column

Tags: qt, search, typing, qtableview

I'm using a QTableView and a subclass of QAbstractTableModel as its model.
I saw that (by default) when the user types something the  QTableView start searching the typed text in the first column and scroll the view to the matching element. This is what I wanted but not in the first column.
I cannot find a way to tell (code) QTableView or QAbstractTableModel which is the "search column".
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTableView usually searches in the column that currently has focus. Just click into a cell in the column you want to search at and start typing.

[Edit:]
Regarding your comment: You can set any cell to the active cell using

```
QTableView* tableView = /* whatever */;
tableView->setCurrentIndex( const QModelIndex& index )
```

This will also select the cell. If you don't want that, you can do

```
QModelIndex index = /* whatever */;
tableView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex( index, QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate );
```

If you have slots connected to your current[Row|Column]Changed or selectionChanged signals of the table view's selectionModel(), you might wanna do the following, dependent on your code:

```
QTableView* tableView = /* whatever */;
QModelIndex index = /* current row, whatever column you want to search in */;

QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel = tableView->selectionModel();
// probably check for a NULL pointer? - not really sure if this is possible

bool signalsWereBlocked = selectionModel->blockSignals( true );
selectionModel->setCurrentIndex( index );
selectionModel->blockSignals( signalsWereBlocked );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
QAbstractItemModel *model = myTableView->model();
QModelIndex index = model->index( 0, SearchColumn ); // whatever column you want to search in
myTableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
//now SearchColumn has focus and future search will operate in this column
```

But if I use a QTreeView instead of a QTableView it doesn't work :(

Comment: Check my edited answer, probably `treeView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(...)` will work as well. I can't tell if a tree view allows the same keyboard search as a table view does, however

Comment: Yes, I checked and treeView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(...) worked as well (and has more options). Thanks!!